# Ubuntu 18.04 server configured with static ipv6 request dhcp ipv6 address

Tags: networking, server, dhcpv6

I'm having trouble understanding why an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS server installed on a bhyve host insists on requesting a dhcpv6 address despite being configured with a static address with dhcp6 off.

```
root@ubs:~# journalctl -u systemd-networkd
    ...
    -- Reboot --
Feb 15 14:01:45 ubs systemd[1]: Starting Network Service...
Feb 15 14:01:45 ubs systemd-networkd[584]: Enumeration completed
Feb 15 14:01:45 ubs systemd[1]: Started Network Service.
Feb 15 14:01:45 ubs systemd-networkd[584]: lo: Link is not managed by us
Feb 15 14:01:45 ubs systemd-networkd[584]: enp0s4: IPv6 successfully enabled
Feb 15 14:01:45 ubs systemd-networkd[584]: enp0s4: Gained carrier
Feb 15 14:01:46 ubs systemd-networkd[584]: enp0s4: Gained IPv6LL
Feb 15 14:01:48 ubs systemd-networkd[584]: enp0s4: DHCPv6 address 2a02:2f04:...::941a/128 timeout preferred 4500 valid 7200
Feb 15 14:01:50 ubs systemd-networkd[584]: enp0s4: Configured
    root@ubs:~# networkctl status enp0s4
    ● 2: enp0s4
           Link File: /lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
        Network File: /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp0s4.network
                Type: ether
               State: routable (configured)
                Path: pci-0000:00:04.0
              Driver: virtio_net
              Vendor: Red Hat, Inc.
               Model: Virtio network device
          HW Address: 00:a0:98:7a:8e:aa (NetApp)
             Address: 10.0.200.11
                      2a02:2f04:...::51
                      2a02:2f04:...::941a
                      2a02:2f04:146:...:8eaa
                      fe80::2a0:98ff:fe7a:8eaa
             Gateway: 10.0.200.1
                 DNS: 2a02:2f04:...::1
      Search Domains: domain.tld
    root@ubs:~#
```

But DHCP v6 is NOT configured:

```
root@ubs:~# cat /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s4:
            addresses:
            - 10.0.200.11/24
            - 2a02:2f04:...::51/64
            dhcp4: false
            dhcp6: false
            gateway4: 10.0.200.1
            gateway6: 2a02:2f04:...::1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 2a02:2f04:...::1
                search:
                - domain.tld
    version: 2
root@ubs:~#
```

Who's sending the solicit message? is this a bug or i'm overlooking something obvious?

Comment: But... you've configured IPv6 addresses, gateway6, and nameservers!

Answer (score 1):

`false` is not an option according to the examples on [the netplan website](https://netplan.io/examples).
However, the netplan reference page states (bool), which makes `true/false` first guess.

```
dhcp4: yes/no
dhcp6: yes/no
```

Comment: ok but very short. Please give some reference information

Comment: The yaml file was generated by the ubuntu installer. Tried replacing false with no..same result.

Comment: if the ipv6 address is not from dhcpv6, check to see if it's your mac address with your 64 prefix.